# Are Runnable and Thread abstract classes?

Tags: java, class, oop, runnable

This question may be silly, I'm quite new to Java and to object-oriented programming. Right now, I'm studying for my semester exams, and I have this question: Are `Runnable` and `Thread` abstract classes?

Comment: Look it up in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

Comment: It's "I'm", not "im", and "I", not "i". I've cleaned things up for you on this occasion.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to __target specific programming problems__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 8):

An *abstract class* is a class with one or more abstract methods (or which is just arbitrarily marked abstract using the `abstract` keyword). With an abstract class, you can't create instances; you must subclass (derive from) the class, implement any abstract methods, and then create instances of the subclass. More in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

[`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) is an interface, and so not an abstract class in the Java sense. However:

- In a more general Computer Science / OOP sense, you could argue that a Java interface is an abstract class, since like an abstract class, it defines a contract but you cannot directly instantiate it, you have to implement it. It is **not** one in the Java sense, but there's an argument for the general case.
- And in Java 8 (although `Runnable` doesn't do this), it's now possible to define interfaces with "default" implementations of methods, which makes the distinction between those interfaces and Java's normal abstract classes quite subtle. (The remaining distinction relates to inheritance; you can't inherit from multiple classes in Java, but you can inherit from one class and any number of interfaces, even ones with default methods.) But again, `Runnable` doesn't have default methods.

[`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) is a class that is not marked `abstract`, has no `abstract` methods, and therefore can be directly instantiated. So it's also not an abstract class in either a Java or general CS sense. However:

- It's a ***bit*** like an abstract class despite not literally being one, as `Thread` is mostly useful only if you subclass it and override its `run` method, or (and this is generally preferred) if you write a class implementing the `Runnable` instance and pass an instance of that into the `Thread` constructor. More in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Comment: Interesting point of view. Thread is the abstract class that is not an abstract class. I can see how that creates confusion and in that light I see far less reason to vote this question down.

Comment: From a CS theory standpoint, a Java `interface` is a pure abstract class. In general one should **not** subclass `Thread`, IMHO it is most useful if you **do not** subclass it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Good point, although I suspect it can be argued both ways. I'll flag it up above, though, because again it's a good point.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Not so much anymore since Java 8 with default method implementations.

Comment: @Gimby Good point, they have become more like normal abstract class, except with multiple inheritance ;)

Comment: @Gimby: LOL, I was just flagging up default methods as well. :-)

Comment: Hey at least we're all on the same page, that adds so much value to this answer!

Comment: A class whose direct instances are useful is _not_ "abstract" in any sense of the word.  Not even if, like `Thread`, an instance must have a delegate in order to do its job.  `Thread` is a bit if a strange case, because it used to be abstract back in the very early days of Java, but it is no way, no how abstract today.

Comment: @jameslarge: Wow, I'd forgotten it used to be abstract until you said that -- we're both old-timers! :-) That was, what, JDK 1.0 I think! Yes, I said firmly that `Thread` is not abstract. What I said, and I think it's reasonable, is that it *"...is a **bit** like..."* which is not saying "it is."

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think Paul Graham said it best, "_has a_ is a more powerful relationship than _is a_."  The `Runnable` argument to the `Thread` constructor is a "delegate."  That is to say, a Thread _has a_ Runnable.  Any time you find yourself wanting to create a family of subclasses, you should stop and ask, "Can I achieve this using interfaces and delegates instead?"  The answer ususally is "yes", and if you do it with delegates, you code probably will be easier to understand, easier to test, and easier to maintain.

Comment: @jameslarge: Very well put indeed. When I first got into OOP, I thought inheritance was the be-all, end-all. I find these days that I use inheritance quite sparingly.